# Как найти индексы в таблице с датами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, индексация

У меня есть таблица с датами `d`:

```
               created_at
0     2020-01-01 18:08:09
1     2020-02-10 23:45:40
2     2020-02-20 09:41:14
3     2020-03-10 13:44:40
```

Необходимо найти индексы дат, которые больше `date_1` и меньше `date_2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

date_1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 02, 10, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=None)
date_2 = datetime.datetime(2020, 03, 10, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=None)

ind = np.where((d >= date_1) & (d < date_2))[0]
print(ind)
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[1, 2]
```

Но появляется ошибка:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'.
```

Не совсем понятно, нужно ли переводить таблицу дат из `str` в формат даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np


d = np.array([
    datetime.strptime('2020-01-01 18:08:09', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime('2020-02-10 23:45:40', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime('2020-02-20 09:41:14', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime('2020-03-10 13:44:40', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
])


date_1 = datetime(2020, 2, 10, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=None)
date_2 = datetime(2020, 3, 10, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=None)

ind = np.where((d >= date_1) & (d < date_2))[0]
print(ind)

[1 2]
```

Comment: Практика показала, что Ваш способ индексирования с помощью 'np.where()' более безопасный, чем с использованием инструментов Pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
d['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(d['created_at'])
idx = d.query('@date_1 < created_at < @date_2').index
```

Answer (score 2):

Если `d` это таблица `Pandas`, то так:

```
ind = d.loc[(d['created_at'] >= date_1) & (d['created_at'] < date_2)].index
```

Но вообще да, даты наверное нужно будет перевести через `pd.to_datetime`.